# How to set DAO global ConsistencyLevel

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Hi datastax java driver experts :)

Does anyone know, how to set ConsistencyLevel globally per DAO or Mapper in Cassandra Datastax java driver 4.14. ?

At the moment I do in the DAO for each method:

DAO:

```
 @Select
  PagingIterable<AppTrackingEvent> findBySessionId(
      final UUID sessionId,
      final Function<BoundStatementBuilder, BoundStatementBuilder> setAttributes);
```

Repository:

```
public List<AppTrackingEvent> getBySessionId(final UUID sessionId) {
    return this.mapper
        .getAppTrackingDao()
        .findBySessionId(
            sessionId,
            statement ->
                statement.setConsistencyLevel(DefaultConsistencyLevel.valueOf(consistencyLevel)))
        .all();
  }
```

on every method for this Entity in my DAO interface and implementation. This is quite annoying, because the ConsistencyLevel is for every method in this DAO always the same.

In an older datastax java driver version there was a convenient solution for that:

```
Mapper.Option.consistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.valueOf(consistencyLevel)));
```

Is this possible in the 4.14 too, and how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to change it as `CqlSession` level. The Cqlsession should be a singleton in your application.

The simplest is to create a file `application.conf` in your classpath with the following [reference](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/core/configuration/reference/)

```
datastax-java-driver {
    basic.request {
        consistency = LOCAL_ONE
    }
}
```

Now if you create your CqlSession programmatically update the proper key

```
DriverConfigLoader loader = DriverConfigLoader
   .programmaticBuilder()
   .withString(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_CONSISTENCY, "LOCAL_ONE")
   // more options
   .build();
try (CqlSession cqlSession = CqlSession.builder().withConfigLoader(loader).build()) {
     ///do stuff
}
```

Comment: My Question is a little bit complex, than that. I asked not globally for the whole java driver. Globally for one `@Dao` or `@Entity`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, but i have a solution.

I have created Profiles:

```
final DriverConfigLoader driverConfigLoader =
    DriverConfigLoader.programmaticBuilder()
        // default from datastax is LOCAL_ONE
        .startProfile("myProfile1")
        .withString(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_CONSISTENCY, "LOCAL_QUORUM")
        .endProfile()
        .startProfile("myProfile2")
        .withString(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_CONSISTENCY, "TWO")
        .endProfile()
        .build();
```

and on initialization:

```
@Bean
public LogEntryMapper getLogEntryMapper(final CqlSession cqlSession) {
return new LogEntryMapperBuilder(cqlSession)
               .withDefaultExecutionProfileName("myProfile1").build();
```

}